# The cable of my USB port hub is too short - what to do?

Tags: usb, cable, hub

I just bought a new USB port hub "MSY USB 2.0 4-port hub".
It has two inputs:

1. A small USB entrance
2. input for external power (?)

The problem is that the cable that comes with the hub (small USB on one end, large USB on the other - to input into my computer), is too short for my needs.

Is there a solution to this?
Buying a longer cable might be risky; I know that it might cause problems with power.

Is there anything else I can do to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be fine with a USB extension cable as long as you remain within the limits of the specification, which if I remember rightly states devices should be no more then 5m (cable length) apart. So if your existing cable is 1m long, you could add a 2m extension and still be well within spec.

Comment: The cable attached is 50cm long (which is really really short). A length of 2 meters would be fine for me.
I'll try to buy that one, and update later. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You could also get an extension, but probably worth getting a whole new cable

Comment: Eventually, I bought a whole new cable, 2m long. It works excellent, and I'm really happy with it :). Thanks again for the answer. Best.

Comment: @Anna: David's correct, but I'd recommend getting a longer cable over an extension.  Any extra connector is an additional failure point, so one long cable is less likely to fail than two shorter cables.